# Windows Phone timed repeating method (like NSTimer in IOS)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

Is there anytihng in WP7.5 like NSTimer in iOS where I can set a method to call once, or repeatedly at a set interval.

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 3):

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dt = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();

dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
dt.Tick +=new EventHandler(dt_Tick);

void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       //code
}
```

and

```
dt.start() ;

dt.stop() ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to do, you'll want to use:

- `Timer`, if you want to start a 'simple' background task : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx
- `DispatcherTimer`, if you want to modify the UI: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: I'd also recommend the Microsoft-supplied [API mapping for iOS to Windows Phone](http://wp7mapping.interoperabilitybridges.com/Library?source=iPhone), as it is quite extensive.